# recurrence relation and asymptotics

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence, $a(n+1) = a(n)+2a(n)^2$, with $a(0) \in (-1,0)$. Can we find a general formula for $a(n)$? Asymptotically tight characterization in $n$ is okay.

What I naively tried is
\begin{align}
a(n+1)-a(n) = 2a(n)^2 \implies a'(t) = 2a(t)^2,
\end{align}
so solving the ODE gives $a(n) = - (c_1 n + c_2)^{-1}$, but not sure this is correct.

Comment: It seems that $a(n) \sim  - \frac{1}{2n}$. Perhaps you can try bounding the error term of this approximation.

Comment: It depends. For $a(0)<-1/2$, $a(1)>0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}=+\infty$, for $a(0)=-1/2$, the sequence is $0$ for $n\ge1$, and for $a(0)\in(-1/2,0)$, you have $a(n)\sim-\frac1{2n}$, indeed.